# Is there a way to sort variables in an array by assigning a percentage to the variable (i.e sorting books by their reading completion progress)?

Tags: java, hashmap, boolean, percentage

I'm trying to create a program that sorts books by the completion progress. So far, I have created a program using java.util.HashMap and boolean variables to display finished and unfinished books by displaying the progress as either "Complete" or "Incomplete." However, I would like to write another method that allows the user to enter a number of pages in the books displayed in the keySet and the number of pages the user has read and will calculate a percentage based on those variables.

```
public void getFinishedBooks (HashMap<String, Boolean> library){ 
      if(library.size() < 1){
         System.out.println("Bye");   
      }
      else {
         for (String book : library.keySet()) {
             System.out.print(book + " ... " + "Progress: ");
             if (library.get(book) == true) {
               System.out.print("Completed.");
               System.out.println();
            }
             else if(library.get(book) == false){
                 System.out.print("Incomplete.");
                 System.out.println();
             }
         }
      }
   
   }
  
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      
       System.out.println("My Books: ");
       
       HashMap<String,Boolean> myBooks=new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
      
      myBooks.put("Final Fantasy XV: Dawn of the Future",true);
      myBooks.put("Kingdom Hearts 358/2 Days: The Novel",false);
      myBooks.put("Fahrenheit 451",true);
      myBooks.put("Beyonders: A World Without Heroes",false);
      
      
      Library myLibrary = new Library();
      myLibrary.getFinishedBooks(myBooks);
        
        
   }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/sort-a-mapkey-value-by-values

Comment: Kinda. I know that a Map can only have two variables `Map<K,V>` but I'm looking to use another variable, which would be user-inputted in the form of total page numbers and amount of pages read, to determine the true/false value.

Comment: You could make a `Book` class to store all the info you want about each book such as title, author, total pages, pages read, completion progress, completed e.t.c Then you can create a `HashMap<String, Book>`. Then use some simple sort to sort with respect to completion progress.